# In Chrome :active state on radio button isn't released on keyup (Space key)

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

As demonstrated in [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kimomaj/edit?html,css,output) I can style radio button label with pseudo selector `:active`. But when i activate the radio button with Space key, as apposed to mouse click, the active state isn't released afterwards.

Can anyone explain this to me? It seems like Firefox and Edge handles it differently.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
  
input:active + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>When a radio button in this group is :active the label background is red.</p>
  
  <p>Works as expected when clicking (the radio button gets "deactivated" again when the mouse button is released).</p>
  
  <p>But if I activate a radio button with the keyboard, key [Space], it <i>isn't</i> deactivated on key up. I can then move to another radio button with the arrow keys (= that button is checked).</p>
  
  <p>Again, I can hit [Space] and now I have <i>two</i> radio buttons in active state.</p>
  
  <p>If I use the arrow keys to navigate to one of these active radio buttons, <i>then</i> it gets deactivated.</p>
  
    <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
    <label for="huey">Huey</label>

    <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
    <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>

    <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
    <label for="louie">Louie</label>

  <p><br>Another group with only one button – same issue:</p>
  
    <input type="radio" id="jonna" name="jonne" value="jonna">
    <label for="jonna">Jonna</label>
```